# set time limit on scikit-learn GridSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn

can I limit the time on each step in GridSearchCV/RandomizedSearchCV iteration of a scikit-learn hyperparameter optimization?

Thank you

Comment: as far as I know, this is not possible in sklearn